# Salvar Inputs de um site em um Banco de Dados

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

Sou iniciante me HTML, JavaScript e afins.
Preciso salva os inputs do usuário do meu site num banco de dados. As minhas páginas, em especial a de cadastro, foi desenvolvida 100% em HTML.
O que preciso fazer é pegar esses INPUTS do formulário e salva-los no meu BD.
Fui aconselhado a fazer uso do JSON, porém nos materiais e artigos que encontrei na net eu não consegui entender com fazer isso.

Gostaria que vocês pudessem me ajudar com esse problema me mostrando um exemplo de como capturar esses dados do formulário em encaminha-los para o meu BD ou me indicando algum material que tenha algum exemplo de como fazer isso.

Comment: Qual o tipo de BD que tens? como queres salvar? via AJAX (post ou get)? ou queres enviar o formulário via API (POST) do HTML? ... eu percebo a tua pergunta mas está ampla demais. Dá para clarificar os pontos que perguntei?

Comment: Boa noite Sergio,
O meu banco é o SQL Server, quero salvar via POST.
Aproveitando a oportunidade, quero salvar e, quando for o caso, também quero resgatar os dados para fazer alguma manipulação.

Desde já agradeço a sua atenção.